# Java Regex to find time between two words in a String

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find the time fields between two specific words in a String. Here is few examples of my inputs

Examples

```
The Big Cat eats at 3:49 AM and the Big Dog eats  Daily (BBB) , On 12 at 5:00 AM done
The Big Cat eats at 3:49 AM and the Big Dog eats  Daily (BBB) , On 12 at 11:00 PM done
```

Expected Output

```
5:00 AM
11:00 PM
```

RegEx Used

```
(?<=Dog\s(\w+))((\d):(\d)(\d)\sAM)(?=\sdone)
```

I dont seem to get it properly. Not sure if the special characters in between are causing the issue. But instead of Alphanumeric, if I use Any character, then all words between my two keywords get captured.
Could anyone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you could use split() twice to do this (and code would be simple) .. Any specific reason for using Regex??..

Comment: if `regex` is not necessary, how about this? `System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf(" at ")+4,str.indexOf(" and ")));` :)

Comment: @RafaEl - My point exactly... There are several ways to do this thing.. And Regex complicates matters..

Comment: @TheLostMind Yes agree with you, `regex` seems not suitable for this case.

Comment: @TheLostMind Could not agree with you more on this, but I am trying to build a tool which does text parsing and I want to keep the design generic by extracting just data using regexes and not manipulate it in my java code

Comment: @immzi -  string.split("s+") . The index 18 will give you the answer.. Why bother using Regex.. It will also have an impact on performance... and Also, how will split() break your design??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
    String val="Big Cat eats at 3:49 AM and the Big Dog eats  Daily (BBB) , On 12 at 11:00 AM done";
    String REGEX="(?:Dog[a-zA-Z0-9(),])*([0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9]?[0-9] (AM|PM))(?=\\sdone)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(val);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

**Explanation:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though @k-mera had already provided the regex. But your regex gives me the time in matching group(0), hence marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
[0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9]?[0-9] AM|PM
```

Assuming your times are always in the form `(x)x:(x)x AM` or `(x)x:(x)x PM`

For clarification:

```
[0-9]  matches any digit from 0-9
?      matches 0 or 1 occurences
x|y    matches x or y
```

But, as others have pointed out, if the string is always the same then it is better to use substring etc. With a regex it gets much more complicated than it needs to be.

---

Edit: to find it between `dog` and `done` do

```
 Dog.*([0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9]?[0-9] AM|PM).*done
```

and use `\1` to get the matched time or make a substring between `Dog` and `done` and use the first regex.

---

Edit2: I added a working [example](http://ideone.com/wSEWMX):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String in = "The Big Cat eats at 3:49 AM and the Big Dog eats  Daily (BBB) , On 12 at 5:00 AM done";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Dog.*([0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9]?[0-9] AM|PM).*done");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(in);

    System.out.println("matching");
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
matching
5:00 AM
```

Comment: This gives me the other times as well, whereas I just need the times between the two keywords "Dog" and "done". I tried replacing the above regex in my expression though, it still didnt give me the result.

Comment: ok. if it is always between the same keywords, find those and use substring between these indices.